# How to query between two x amount of days using Laravel and Carbon?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, php-carbon

I'm trying to retrieve data from the past 30 to 60 days. Which means I'm leaving out days 0 to 30 and everything past day 60.

My current progress is as such:

```
$previousMonth = DB::table('table')
->select('table.*')
->whereBetween('date', [Carbon::now()->subDays(30), Carbon::now()->subDays(60)])
->get();

return $previousMonth;
```

"date" has the datatype of DATETIME in mysql database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the order, because `Carbon::now()->subDays(30)` is greater than `Carbon::now()->subDays(60)`, and you can use `startOfDay()` to get start of day:

```php
->whereBetween('date', [Carbon::now()->subDays(60)->startOfDay(), Carbon::now()->subDays(30)->startOfDay()])
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this `startOfDay()`

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

$previousMonth = DB::table('table')
->select('table.*')->whereBetween('date', [Carbon::now()->subDays(60)->startOfDay(), Carbon::now()->subDays(30)->startOfDay()])->get();

return $previousMonth;
```

Refer This Link

http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Comment: Yes, it's the same awnser as @TsaiKoga gave me which worked just perfect! Thanks for the added documentation. Very much appreciated.